# Form validation error always visible in asp.netcore

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, controller

I have a simple Login form with a single input field like :

```
<form asp-action="SendLoginEmail" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <input asp-for="EmailAddress" placeholder="Adresse mail" class="form-control"/>
        <div class="row">
            <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress"></span>
            @if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ErrorMessage))
            {
                <span class="field-validation-error">@Model.ErrorMessage</span>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" id="login-button" class="challenge-action-item green-action-button link-button">Continuer</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here are the controllers :

```
[HttpGet("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult LoginGet(LoginModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPost(LoginModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Login", model);
    }
    ...
}

[HttpPost("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Whatever(LoginModel model)
{
    var error = "The one time login link has expired";
    return RedirectToAction("Login", new LoginModel() {ErrorMessage = error});
}
```

On top of the validation errors, I also populate the ErrorMessage from the model to let the user know of potential errors server side like (the email address is not recognized, the one time login link has expired (from a redirection) etc...)

So without those additional errors, i could just remove the LoginModel argument from the Get Login controller and it would work well. But as I want to pass custom messages on top of the validation, I have to have the model argument. But in turn, it means that even when I load the page without anything in it, it will show the validation error (in this case, Email is required).

What are my options ?

Comment: Since there's two same `Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)` methods in the controller , I doubt whether it can succeed to compile .

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this issue so we can focus on the actual question

Answer (score 1):

> But as I want to pass custom messages on top of the validation, I have to have the model argument.

You actually don’t. You can just use the model state for this too. While the model validation errors are usually set automatically by the validation framework, there is nothing wrong with adding your own model errors on top of those.

For example, the login POST action could look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, model.RememberMe);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }

    // add additional error message
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Login failed");
    return View(model);
}
```

So you are not limited to expanding your view model with artifical error messages just to display custom model errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, but that might not be the cleanest. Instead of putting the custom error message in the model, pass it via the ViewData like so:

```
[HttpGet("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult LoginGet(string errorMessage = null)
{
    ViewData["loginErrorMessage"] = errorMessage;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPost(LoginModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Login", model);
    }
    ...
}

[HttpPost("login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Whatever(LoginModel model)
{
    var error = "The one time login link has expired";
    return RedirectToAction("Login", new {errorMessage = error};
}
```

Comment: It seems that there's no need to add a `string errorMessage` , because
`LoginViewModel.ErrorMessage` will be null if the `LoginGet` render the view by `return View("Login");`